Flutter. Exception has occurred. FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build
Greetings all dear friends, I am asking for your help, I am new to programming and would like to ask you how can I get rid of this error and why it happened? I am trying to create alerts for a user in case the password does not match the conditions, I am trying to update the state of a variable to change the state of a custom checkbox.
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This RegistrationScreen widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
RegistrationScreen
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
TextFormField)
passwordRepeat: InputField(
              controller: _confirmPasswordController,
              labelText: 'Repeat password',
              obcureText: true,
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/icons/lock.svg',
                width: 32,
                height: 32,
              ),
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: _passMatch
                    ? null
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/icons/alert-circle.svg',
                      ),
              ),
              autoValidate: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (value) {

                if (value == null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _passMatch = false;
                  });

                  return 'Repeat password';
                }
                if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                  _passMatch = false;

                  return 'Not match';
                } else {
                  _passMatch = true;
                }
            
                if (value.length >= 8) {
                  setState(() {
                    _minSymbolsError = true;
                    _minSymbolsValid = false;
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _minSymbolsError = true;
                    _minSymbolsValid = false;
                  });
                }
                

                return null;
              },

This is the code for my input field



When you enter this page the build method executes immediately to build the UI. Somewhere in your code is being executed another build or setState method at pararel time with the page build.

You're right, I just didn't understand how to solve this problem. The solution helped me to wrap "setState" in
"Widgets Binding.instance.add Post Frame Callback((timeStamp) {}"

Try this: SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { });
It's a better solution i think. Widgets Binding.instance.add Post Frame Callback((timeStamp) {} also works fine.

I am not sure, but it seems that setState() method is called inside the validator function automatically during the build process.
So it will trigger rebuild. Again, setState will be called inside validator automatically and so on... Which causes the problem.
Also, according to the official documentation of setState():

Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
be associated with the change.

Try extracting setState to functions outside of the build method. For example:
 void _changePassMatch() {
setState(() {
  _passMatch = false;
});
}

Finally, I suggest, checking this link from flutter officials for common errors and how to fix them.

Your option also didn't help, the error remained the same, it helped me solve the problem, I wrapped "setState" in
"WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {}"
